# ignore comments when tracking/approving changes in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I use the Track Changes feature of Word extensively as I work with several other people on the same document.

I always need to approve the comments when going over the changes, this gets very tedious in the long run. I approved each comment several times now, yet I always need to approve them again and again.

Is there any way how I can ignore comments when tracking/approving changes?

I only want to work with actual changes to the document text, not with the comments (which don't change anyway).

--

I am using MS Word 2010 under Windows 7

Comment: The comments is part of the word file .. so, there's no way ..

Comment: @matzone: then how come that even if I do approve each comment, I need to approve the comments *again* when I open the file again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Review tab, in the Tracking group, there is a Show Markup dropdown. If you uncheck Comments, the comments will not be displayed and going through the tracked changes will skip them (since they can't be seen anyway). If there are no other tracked changes, trying to go to the next change makes Word pop up a message that all comments and tracked changes are hidden.

Note that accepting and rejecting comments works differently than accepting or rejecting changes. Accepting a comment does nothing; rejecting a comment deletes the comment. The main buttons on the Review tab are somewhat confusingly named; they are actually Accept/Reject and move to next, not just Accept and Reject. (Accept/Reject and stay where I am are on the main buttons' dropdown menus.) For comments, that actually translates to Do nothing and move to next and Delete comment and move to next; that's why you had to "accept" them every time you through the document.

## Newer versions of Word

The answer above is correct for Word 2010, which was specified in the original question. The behavior has changed somewhat in later versions of Word. The general technique still works, but no dialog appears. Instead, Word silently redisplays the comments once there are no actual changes remaining.

Comment: in the latest office 365, when i deselect comments in the tracking group under show markup, they disappear, but then when i click next change, the comments reappear again. so this solution does not seem to work.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure about Office 365. In the non-365 version of Word 2019, it works but doesn't show a dialog. Instead, it silently turns the comments back on if there are no other tracked changes. The question was tagged as Word 2010; the answer does describe how that version behaved.

Comment: confirmed, this only happens when there are no other tracked changes in office 365. so it does still work - just have to remember this corner case

Comment: @Richard Thanks for confirming. I've updated the answer accordingly.